# SQL table with a single row?

Tags: sql, schema

What is the point (if any) in having a table in a database with only one row?

Note: I'm not talking about the possibility of having only one row in a table, but when a developer deliberately makes a table that is intended to always have exactly one row.

**Edit:**

The sales tax example is a good one.

I've just observed in some code I'm reviewing three different tables that contain three different kinds of certificates (a la SSL), each having exactly one row. I don't understand why this isn't made into one large table; I assume I'm missing something.

Comment: If you can, why not ask the developer for an explanation in person?

Comment: Also, doesn't this lead to a 'programming smell'? Since there are no mechanisms in a database that you can use to specify a table with a single row, would it be possible to accidentally place two elements in the table and use incorrect data when you query it later?

Comment: @Jeremy: You can abuse mechanisms in most RDBMes to enforce a 1 row limit - Such as definining a primary key (or unique key) column, and then also adding a check constraint on the same column that permits only one value. It's not pleasant, though

Comment: I think this is a valid question, it is a "why benefit does this approach have" and that is a good question type.

Comment: An argument for single row table is that you can store configuration data and then also do your data modeling in SQL. One of your configuration options has a foreign key? No problem!

Comment: The way to achieve a single row table is to have an `id` column as `BOOL NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE` and make that unique. Or a stronger way is using `ENUM` with only one case.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've seen something like this when a developer was asked to create a configuration table to store name-value pairs of data that needs to persist without being changed often. He ended up creating a one-row table with a column for each configuration variable. I wouldn't say it's a good idea, but I can certainly see why the developer did it given his instructions. Needless to say it didn't pass review.

> I've just observed in some code I'm reviewing three different tables that contain three different kinds of certificates (a la SSL), each having exactly one row. I don't understand why this isn't made into one row; I assume I'm missing something.

This doesn't sound like good design, unless there are some important details you don't know about. If there are three pieces of information that have the same constraints, the same use and the same structure, they should be stored in the same table, 99% of the time. That's a big part of what tables are for fundamentally.

Comment: Yeah, this was my impression as well, but I thought that maybe there were some special speedups for 'singleton' tables (singleton might not be the right word here, but you get the idea)

Comment: No boost that the right clustered index wouldn't provide.

Comment: Welbog given the constraint for your case that you mention what would be the good design option?

Answer (score 17):

It's not necessarily a bad idea.

What if you had some global state (say, a boolean) that you wanted to store somewhere?  And you wanted your stored procedures to easily access this state?

You could create a table with a primary key whose value range was limited to exactly one value.

Answer (score 16):

For some things you only need one row - typically system configuration data. For example, "current sales tax rate". This might change in the future and so shouldn't be hardcoded, but you'll typically only ever need one at any given time. This kind of data needs to be in the database so that queries can use it in computations.

Comment: Then do you have each state as a column?
ie: Select California From CurrentSalesTaxRate ?

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of this, for instance here in Canada, our national sales tax has changed twice in the last 5 years, and provincial ones are being changed as well. So a table of sales tax with a tax/rate/effective/expiry date works best.

Comment: Depends on the application. For example, if you need to handle multiple sales tax rates for different states, it wouldn't be in a single-row table; but if you're doing a single-country application in Europe, say, you might put the Value Added Tax rate into such a table.

Comment: Using a tax rate was just an example. There are lots of other configuration items which change much less often.

Comment: For simple system configuration data, I would consider a key-value pair table with a row for each configuration item.

Comment: And if there was only one configuration item, there would only be one row in the table :-)

Comment: @JasonMusgrove However even a simple set of system configuration data can easily contain values of different types. Integers, strings and bools for example. Of course we cannot make a new key-value table for each different value type, so then we are back to the single row table.

Answer (score 6):

Single row is like a singleton class. purpose: to control or manage some other process.

Single row table could act as a critical section or as deterministic automaton (kind of dispatcher based on row values)

Single row is use full in a table COMPANY_DESCRIPTION, to obtain consistent data about that company. Use full on company letters and addressing.

Single row is use full to contain an actual value like VAT or Date or Time, and so on.

Answer (score 4):

It can be useful sometime to emulate some features the Database system doesn't provide. I'm thinking of sequences in MySQL for instance.

Comment: why not? many developers used table look like these table to store `settings` for example  for the script i think it good idea and more secure rather than xml file because its readable

Answer (score 4):

> What is the point (if any) in having a table in a database with only one row?

A relational database stores things as relations: a tuples of data satisfying some relation.

Like, this one: "a `VAT` of *this many percent* is in effect in my country now".

If only one tuple satisifies this relation, then yes, it will be the only one in the table.

`SQL` cannot store variables: it can store a set consisting of `1` element, this is a one-row table.

Also, `SQL` is a set based language, and for some operations you need a fake set of only one row, like, to select a constant expression.

You cannot just `SELECT` out of nothing in `Oracle`, you need a `FROM` clause.

`Oracle` has a pseudotable, `dual`, which contains only one row and only one column.

Once, long time ago, it used to have *two* rows (hence the name `dual`), but lost its second row somewhere on its way to version `7`.

`MySQL` has this pseudotable too, but `MySQL` is able to do selects without `FROM` clause. Still, it's useful when you need an empty rowset: `SELECT 1 FROM dual WHERE NULL`

> I've just observed in some code I'm reviewing three different tables that contain three different kinds of certificates (a la `SSL`), each having exactly one row. I don't understand why this isn't made into one large table; I assume I'm missing something.

It may be a kind of "have it all or lose" scenario, when all three certificates are needed at once:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    ssl1
CROSS JOIN
        ssl2
CROSS JOIN
        ssl3
```

If any if the certificates is missing, the whole query returns nothing.

Comment: I definitely don't see the coss join pattern here, but that's a good point.

Comment: @Jeremy: if you don't need any other condition except for mere presense or absense of a row, `CROSS JOIN` is what you need.

Answer (score 4):

If your database is your application, then it probably makes sense for storing configuration data that might be required by stored procedures implementing business logic.

If you have an application that could use the file system to store information, then I don't think there is an advantage to using the database over an XML or flat file, except maybe that most developers are now far more well versed in using SQL to store and retrieve data than accessing the file system.

Answer (score 3):

A table with a single row can be used to store application level settings that are shared across all database users.  'Maximum Allowed Users' for example.

Answer (score 3):

Funny... I asked myself the same question. If you just want to store some simple value and your ONLY method of storage is an SQL server, that's pretty much what you have to do. If I have to do this, I usually end up creating a table with several columns and one row. I've seen a couple commercial products do this as well.

Answer (score 2):

We have used a single-row table in the past (not often).  In our case, this table was used to store system-wide configuration values that were updatable via a web interface.  We could have gone the route of a simple name/value table, but the end client preferred a single row.  I personally would have preferred the latter, but it really is up to preference, especially if this table will never have any sort of relationship with another table.

Comment: The single table was likely a better idea than a name value table. Ugh I cringe just at the thought of someone using one of those if there is any alternative as they can be horrible for performance.

Answer (score 2):

I really cannot figure out why this would be the best solution.  It seams more efficient to just have some kind of config file that will contain the data that would be in the tables one row.  The cost of connecting to the database and querying the one row would be more costly.  However if this is going to be some kind of config for the database logic.  Then this would make a little bit more sense depending on the type of database you are using.

Comment: When these settings must be managed by non-developers, that makes much more sense to use a single row table to store system settings.

Answer (score 2):

I use the totally awesome rails-settings plugin for this http://github.com/Squeegy/rails-settings/tree/master

It's really easy to set up and provides a nice syntax:

```
  Settings.admin_password = 'supersecret'
  Settings.date_format    = '%m %d, %Y'
  Settings.cocktails      = ['Martini', 'Screwdriver', 'White Russian']
  Settings.foo            = 123
```

Want a list of all the settings?

```
  Settings.all            # returns {'admin_password' => 'super_secret', 'date_format' => '%m %d, %Y'}
```

Set defaults for certain settings of your app. This will cause the defined settings to return with the Specified value even if they are not in the database. Make a new file in config/initializers/settings.rb with the following:

```
Settings.defaults[:some_setting] = 'footastic'
```

Comment: I do the exact same thing for settings in my sql server db! =)

Answer (score 2):

A use for this might be to store the current version of the database.

If one were storing database versions for schema changes it would need to reside within the database itself.

I currently analyse the schema and update accordingly but am thinking of moving to versioning. Unless someone has a better idea.

I use vb.net and sql express

Answer (score 1):

Unless there are insert constraints on the table a timestamp for versioning then this sounds like a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

There was a table set up like this in a project I inherited.  It was for configuration data, and the reason that was given was that it made for very simple queries:

```
SELECT WidgetSize FROM ConfigTable
SELECT FooLength  FROM ConfigTable
```

Okay fine.  We converted to a generalized configuration table:

```
ID  Name  IntValue StringValue TextValue
```

This has served our purposes well.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE VERSION (VERSION_STRING VARCHAR2(20 BYTE))
```

?

Answer (score 1):

I used a single datum in a SQLite database as a counter in a dynamic web page. That's the simplest way I can think of to make it thread-safe (or process-safe to be precise). But I am not sure whether it's a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to deal with these scenarios is to, rather than using a database at all, use the configuration file (which is usually XML) or make your own configuration file that is read during start up of the application. It only takes a few minutes to write the code to read the file in.

The advantage here is that the there is no chance accidentally adding additional values for the same XML variable, and its great for testing because you don't need to write a lot of code to test the different inputs, just a simple change to the text value and re-run the application.